# Replace all dot characters between single quotes using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have next

```
$pattern = "~'(.*?)\\.(.*?)'~i";
$replacement = "'\\1\\\\x2e\\2'"
$subject = "window.location.href='example.com'";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

It work nice and I got

```
"window.location.href='example\x2ecom'"
```

But if I have

```
$subject = "window.location.href='www.example.com'";
```

or

```
$subject = "window.location.href='www.example.example.com'";
```

I have dots in string.

Please help with `$replacement`

**UPDATE:**

I need get string where all dots in `''` should be `\x2e`

If I have

```
"window.location.href='www.example.example.com'"
```

then I need

```
"window.location.href='www\x2eexample\x2eexample\x2ecom'"
```

Comment: What is expected output for `'www.example.example.com'`?

Comment: www\x2eexample\x2eexample\x2ecom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a positive lookahead and a negated character class in order to only match the literal `.` characters at the end of the string between the `'` characters:

```
$pattern = "~\\.(?=[^']*'$)~i";
```

#### Explanation:

- `\\.` - Match the `.` character literally.
- `(?=` - Start of a positive lookahead.
- `[^']*'$` - Match the preceding character literally, `.`, if it is followed by zero or more non-`'` characters followed by `'` at the end of the string.
- `)` - End of the positive lookahead.

In other words, only the `.` characters between `'` characters at the end of your string will be matched.

[**Example Here**](https://ideone.com/b1GDZS)

```
$pattern = "~\\.(?=[^']*'$)~i";
$replacement = "\\x2e";
$subject = "window.location.href='www.example.com'";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Output:

```
"window.location.href='www\x2eexample\x2ecom'"
```

---

**Based on your comment(s) below:**

If there are multiple occurrences of the substring `window.location.href='.*'`, then you could use the alternation `(?:$|;)` so that it matches up until the last `;` or the end of the string, `$`.

```
$pattern = "~\\.(?=[^']*'(?:$|;))~i";
```

[**Example Here**](https://ideone.com/Xw8WQD)

```
$pattern = "~\\.(?=[^']*'(?:$|;))~i";
$replacement = "\\x2e";
$subject = "window.location.href='.www.test.test.com.'; window.location.href='.www.test.test.com.';";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Output:

```
"window.location.href='\x2ewww\x2etest\x2etest\x2ecom\x2e'; window.location.href='\x2ewww\x2etest\x2etest\x2ecom\x2e';"
```

Comment: I need get string where all dots in '' should be \x2e If I have "window.location.href='www.example.example.com'", then I need "window.location.href='www\x2eexample\x2eexample\x2ecom'"

Comment: It's good answer, but not work if string "window.location.href='.www.test.test.com.'; window.location.href='.www.test.test.com.';"

Comment: @SergeiVeit What exactly are you expecting that to return?

Comment: "window.location.href='\x2ewww\x2etest\x2etest\x2ecom\x2e'; window.location.href='\x2ewww\x2etest\x2etest\x2ecom\x2e';"

Comment: @SergeiVeit Updated.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: sorry it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea using `preg_replace_callback` instead of `preg_replace`.  It allows you to pass in a function to operate on each match.

```
$subject = "window.location.href='example.com.com.com.com.com'";

$subject = preg_replace_callback("~(?<=')(.*?)(?=')~", function($m) {return preg_replace('~\.~', '\x2e', $m[1]);}, $subject);

print $subject;
```

This will output:

```
window.location.href='example\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom'
```

Basically what we're doing here is matching everything inside of the ticks.  Then, when it finds a match, it swaps out each dot for `\x2e` within that string.

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/eYh2rO

Comment: It's good answer too, but not work if string "window.location.href='.www.test.test.com.'; window.location.href='.www.test.test.com.';" - I got result "window.location.href='example\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom';window\x2elocation\x2ehref='example\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom\x2ecom';"

Comment: The problem with this approach is when you have several parts enclosed between quotes. Since quotes aren't consumed (because you use lookarounds), the pattern isn't able to know what is an opening quote and what is a closing quote. This problem can be solved if you remove lookarounds, and if you add quotes in the callback function. As an aside, you should use `str_replace` (or `strtr`) in the callback function since you are replacing a literal string.

Comment: Yes, definitely.  I was just going off of his example.  But yes, you can move the quotes to the function and it would work with all sorts of strings.

Comment: I made a new demo with your new string, replacing the lookarounds with ticks and then adding them in to the returned string.  You can see it here: http://ideone.com/sOIq6J

Comment: @Quixrick: Yes that's the idea.